# How to select an option in Ubuntu - SSH

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-12.04, putty

Guys it may sound dumb but this is my first day working with SSH. 
I have never used commandline before. Can someone tell me how do I select an option at this stage. I am on a Putty Session using SSH on a Ubuntu server trying to configure my VPS.

[image]

I can scroll using the arrows, but pressing enter does not choose the option. May be it is an multiple select option. Using tab takes me to the  button. If I keep navigate down to en (English) and then use Tab to OK it still submits blank. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tab` key to jump between widgets, the cursor keys to move between positions and the `space` key to toggle a selection.

To finish the dialog position the cursor over the `<Ok>` "button" (using the `tab` key again) and press `Enter`.

This is the typical behavior of an "ncurses" based interface. It has nothing to do with ssh or the system you use.

Comment: Thanks arkascha! That was very quick and helpful.